# Editing withdraw during the approving process?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

What I mean is, if your edit is still a suggestion and is pending review.. And after the first rejection, is there an option to withdraw the suggestion by yourself. Not only to avoid the rejection but to have a chance to repair and correct yourself next time. I think it will be ok.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot withdraw a suggested edit once it has been made.

If you found a mistake, though, you *can* make additional edits to your suggestion and your submission will be updated to reflect those different changes. This does not clear previous Reject votes, but if you've corrected your edit then it should get approved.

Comment: And if it does not, we have at least two good reviewers looking bad for rejecting a sterling edit ;-)

Comment: Curiously, I just tried to do this while not logged in, and keep getting the "this post has been deleted" error message, even though it hasn't. (Could be somehow related to being behind a widely-used IP, which hasn't been the case for me until recently.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks That trick will only work for users logged in. Anonymous users wouldn't be able to re-edit a suggested edit. Though that's an interesting error message to get.

Answer (score 1):

No, and I doubt the usefulness of it.

You should make sure your edit is totally perfect. If you doubt that, don't hit the Edit button.

If you feel your edit is totally okay, one reviewer that rejects your edit shouldn't bring you off that much.

Here on SO, there are three votes needed, so just wait on the opinion of the remaining reviewers.