# Withdraw suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

It has happened to me a few times already, that I edited a question only to find out afterwards that someone else has already [taken care of it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28925070/revisions).

In such cases, the other edit is usually either

- close enough to mine to leave it as is,
- totally identical
- or even supersedes my suggested edit

I already searched for such a feature and the only thing I found was an answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276751/editing-withdraw-during-the-approving-process/276754?s=1%7C0.1774#276754) saying that it's not possible. But this is not about my edit being rejected as in the above question, but there are at least two other good reasons I would like to withdraw my edit:

1. My edit is actually wasting the time of reviewers with an unnecessary edit
2. If the other edit is better than mine and mine gets approved anyway (I've had this happen at least once, how could that even happen?), my edit lowers the quality of the question/answer and that's the opposite of what I intended.

So, I'd like to suggest that it's either possible to withdraw suggested edits or to display a warning that the question/answer has been edited in the meantime and that the user should confirm that their edit still supersedes the new edit.

Comment: [MSE dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80933/179419); can't find it as a feature-request on MSO yet.

Comment: If somebody edits while your edit is pending, they either choose to reject your edit or approve it and then layer theirs on top of it. In no case does your edit stick around as a suggested edit.

Comment: This is about someone editing at the same time, not after I'm finished. Look at the example I linked. I started editing before the first edit was there and when I submitted my suggestion, the other edit has already been made and mine was a suggestion on top of that instead of a suggestion on top of the original version.