# Additional feedback on rejected edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

In an effort to become a better Stack Overflow community member, I am seeking some feedback on [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14574316) to [an answer re importing data into SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049109/how-to-import-sql-into-sqlite3/2049137#2049137).

Mostly, it was intended to synthesize the question author's comments throughout the answers, and consolidate other answers so the response could be used as a permanent one-stop reference.

The edit:

1. Added an alternative method that works
2. Highlighted some gotchas (although not part of the original question, additional errors were mentioned in the comments by the question author as reasons his attempts didn't work).
3. Made some formatting changes.

My suspicion is the reviewers focused on #3, the formatting changes, to the exclusion of #1 and #2, which I thought important.

The feedback reason was consistent:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

There are many "ors" in the generic feedback. Which of them most likely applied to the rejection? (Is my intuition correct, and the addition of formatting got in the way of the substantive changes?)

Comment: That edit should've been reviewed by the answer's author.

Comment: I would have rejected straightaway just because of the wildly inappropriate formatting. I suspect others did the same thing. There's no need for headings there in what is otherwise a very short answer, and certainly there's no reason for them to be in a giant, bold font. It's just distracting. So distracting I wouldn't read the rest of your edit. (Which, as answers below point out, is problematic for other reasons.)

Comment: I had reject for the "actively harm readability" part of the rejection reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a solution to a question that you'd like to add, then you should post your own answer, not edit your own solution into someone else's answer.  (In this case, there is already another answer with the solution you were trying to add in, so there is no need to do so.  Feel free to upvote that other answer if you prefer its solution.)

If someone posts an answer with problems or missing content, or other users indicate that they have a problem with that answer in comments, you should not be changing the underlying content of the answer in response to those critiques.  The author of the answer can adjust their answer if they feel it's merited. Like before, if you feel you have something to add that other answers haven't addressed, you can do so in your own answer.  If *the author of the answer* included additional information in comments, you could edit that information into the answer, but that's not the case here.

Your formatting changes were simply inappropriate; you made text into headers that most certainly shouldn't have been formatted as a header.

Comment: The added solution was one mentioned by the question author in the comments. As I understand the [edit policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) adding additional information only found in comments (#1 & #2) is appropriate to edit. You're saying only the answer author should be making these edits? (And thank you for the feedback re formatting.)

Comment: @alttag It's appropriate to edit in content *the post author* has provided in comments.  It's not appropriate to edit anything into an answer just because someone posted that information in a comment on that answer.  If the author has provided some content in a comment, it's fine to move that author's content from one of their comments into their answer; they don't need to be the one to make the edit.  The point is that you shouldn't be adding content to the answer if it's not the author's content; if they posted it in a content, then it is the original author's content.

Comment: Also note that obvious spelling mistakes were introduces. "Does" is not spelled "dos".

Comment: Only integrating the answer author's comments seems exceptionally more specific than the generic language found in the [edit FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). If that's the community standard, it would be useful information to have documented there. Thank you for that clarification.

Comment: @meagar, yes, I saw it after hitting submit. Certainly a downer, but I'd hoped easily corrected.

Comment: @alttag There are a lot of edits to review, good and bad, and if you introduce trivial spelling mistakes, that's generally going to be an immediate rejection, and rightfully so. Your edit should never introduce work for somebody else.

Comment: Probably not an appropriate question for the comment, but is there a way to withdraw a proposed edit? e.g., http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287623/withdraw-suggested-edit

Comment: @alttag No, there is not.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to editing in your own unrelated answer to somebody else's, there's actually a lot wrong here with the text you tried to introduce:

- "SQLite" could be spelled "SQLite" when referring to the product, or `sqlite` when referring to the command line utility, but never  "sqLite", which you incorrectly tried to introduce
- "Does" is not spelled "dos", which is an obvious spelling mistake your edit introduced
- You added all kinds of cruft that contributes nothing but filler to the appropriately succinct answer. Phrases like "any of the following will work" add no value, and you took several short *succinct* sentences and made them longer for absolutely no reason. Why edit this simple sentence, which clearly states the problem and solution...

  > Also, your SQL is invalid - you need `;` on the end of your statements

  into two redundant sentences adding absolutely no additional useful information:

  > Double check that your SQL is valid!
  >
  > Your SQL is invalid - you need `;` on the end of your statements:

Verbose is not inherently good. Your posts should be as short a possible while still clearly communicating your idea.

Comment: Thanks for the additional feedback, @meagar. +1

Comment: As for the second change (after your edit to this answer), it was intended to highlight the additional reasons the question author noted his SQL was invalid in the comments, not just the one the answer author noticed. Although this was also part of the edit, your point about verbosity is well stated. Per @Servy below, those additions were not appropriate because they weren't from the answer author. Thanks for not just answering, but taking the time to be thorough in your response.